# SQL - How to Count Multiple Occurrences of Values in One Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a `StatusID` column that has many different possible values, what I  am trying to do is produce a report in the following format that is able to produce a count of various criteria.

**Desired Output:**

```
Notes | Total | Valid | Invalid | Consults Booked |
```

Total is count of all rows returned - already in the below query

Valid is any `StatusID` that is not `5`,`7` or `42`

Invalid is the count of `5`, `7` and `42`

Consults Booked is the count of `4`

(Invalid + Valid should equal Total)

So far I can only manage to get the `Total`, I have no idea how to determine the other values using `IF` or anything else.

**Query so far**

```
select notes, tLeadStatus.Status, tLeadStatus.StatusID,
       count(*) as Total from LeadManagement.dbo.tLead with (NOLOCK)
left join LeadManagement.dbo.tInternetLead on tLead.Leadid = tinternetlead.leadid
left join LeadManagement..tLeadStatus on tLeadStatus.StatusID = tLead.Status
where (CampaignID = '12327')
  and (registerdate >= '2013-03-01' and registerdate < '2013-04-01')
group by notes,tLeadStatus.StatusID,tLeadStatus.Status
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID NOT IN (5, 7, 42) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Valid,
SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID IN (5, 7, 42) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Invalid,
SUM(CASE WHEN StatusId = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Consults Booked'
```

Comment: ah, didn't realise it could be done like that.... thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE to get the other columns:

```
select notes, 
  count(*) as Total,
  sum(case when tLeadStatus.StatusID not in (5, 7, 42) then 1 else 0 end) Valid,
  sum(case when tLeadStatus.StatusID  in (5, 7, 42) then 1 else 0 end) Invalid,
  sum(case when tLeadStatus.StatusID= 4 then 1 else 0 end) ConsultsBooked
from LeadManagement.dbo.tLead with (NOLOCK)
left join LeadManagement.dbo.tInternetLead 
  on   tLead.Leadid = tinternetlead.leadid
left join LeadManagement..tLeadStatus 
  on tLeadStatus.StatusID = tLead.Status
where (CampaignID = '12327')
  and (registerdate >= '2013-03-01' and registerdate < '2013-04-01')
group by notes
```